# Can I make a line with both a slant asymptote and a horizontal.

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Why can’t you create an equation of a line that gets closer to a line as it heads to $\infty,$ such as $y=x$ or $y=2x+4$ and a horizontal asymptote that approaches something like $-2$ as it goes towards $-\infty.$  Can somebody please help me build an equation for this line.               (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYaVS.jpg)

Comment: Of course one can do that with a complicated enough function. The question is which functions are allowed. E.g. a rational function could *not* fulfill this, because if it has a horizontal asymptote towards $-\infty$ it must have the same h.a. towards $+\infty$.

Comment: But maybe you want to take a look at the graph of $x\cdot(\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2})$, and adjust by stretching and shifting.

Answer (score 4):

As said by @Torsten Schoeneberg there are many ways to obtain such curves. However, (branches of) hyperbolas rank among the most natural ones.

Thus I propose the following general solution among the hyperbola family : for any real parameter $a>0$

$$y=\dfrac12\left(x-2+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+4a}\right)$$

[image]

Fig. Different branches for $a=0.5, 1, 1.5, ...4$.

How did I find this general equation ?

I have first considered the curve reduced to its asymptotes, i.e., with equation

$$(y+2)(y-x)=0 \tag{1}$$

(the product of equations $y+2=0$ and $y-x=0$). Then I pertubated a little this equation by taking instead of it :

$$(y+2)(y-x)-a=0 \tag{2}$$

Now expand it as a quadratic in variable $y$ :

$$y^2+y(2-x)-(2x+a)=0 \tag{3}$$

and use the classical formula for the roots of a quadratic considering $x$ as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a function with asymptotes $\;y=-2\;$ as $\;x\to -\infty\;$ and $\;y=x-2\;$ as $x\to \infty\;$ is $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{2}-2$$ [image: (picture by WolframAlpha]

Comment: The slant asymptote of this is $y = x-2$.

Comment: Right, thanks. Going to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To amend my second comment, for what it's worth, here is my thought process how to get a function as demanded, and what I experienced when doing that "shifting and stretching".

So to start, I looked for a function with two different horizontal asymptotes for $x \to -\infty$ versus $x \to \infty$. Well, the $\arctan$ came to my mind. Now first I wanted to turn that in the general shape "0 on the left, but positive (so I can make it increasing) on the right". So I moved it up by $\pi/2$, whence it would go from $0$ at $-\infty$ to $\pi$ (or whatever positive value) at $\infty$.

$\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$:

[image]

This, multiplied with $\frac{x}{\pi}$, will give something that will behave like $0$ to the left, but like $x$ on the right (so I thought):

$\displaystyle \frac{x}{\pi} \cdot \left(\arctan(x) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$:

[image]

Now shift it down by $2$. That will make $\lim_{x\to -\infty} =-2$, I thought. It also moves the slant asymptote down to $y=x-2$. To make good for that, I thought I move the graph to the left by $2$, which transforms the slant asymptote back to $y=x$ and does not change the horizontal one.

$\displaystyle \frac{x+2}{\pi} \cdot \left(\arctan(x) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) -2$:

[image]

But now I noticed that ever since the second step I was off by a vertical shift of $1/\pi$. See, both asymptotes are a bit too low. Where does that come from? Well I realised that even though arctan goes to $\pm\pi/2$ (and my shifted version in the first step to $0$ resp. $\pi$), I multiply it with a linear term; which means that I have to find out how well the $\arctan$ approaches its limit *up to a term of order $\frac1x$*. And indeed, an expansion of $\arctan$ "around $\pm \infty$" is given by

$$\displaystyle \arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^{3}} - \frac{1}{5x^{5}} + ...$$ (for $x >1$) resp.

$$\displaystyle \arctan(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^{3}} - \frac{1}{5x^{5}} + ...$$ (for $x < -1$).

whose $-1/x$-term, by multiplication with $x/\pi$, indeed explained that constant $-1/\pi$ term. But then that's that,  one just removes it by hand, giving:

> $$f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x+2}{\pi} \cdot \left(\arctan(x) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) -2 +\frac{1}{\pi}$$

Voilà:

[image]

---

Fun fact I learned on the way when deriving the "expansion around $\infty$": the derivative of $\arctan(1/x)$ is $(-1)\cdot$ the derivative of $\arctan(x)$; which abstractly implies that $\arctan(x)= C - \arctan(1/x)$ for some constant depending on the connected component of the graph we are on. And indeed e.g. for $x>0$, we have $\arctan(x) = \pi/2 - \arctan(1/x)$.